# Error installing aerospike client on mac

Tags: aerospike

Unsure how to fix this. I have run the below command on my mac.

> sudo pip install aerospike

I have installed Lua

```
ld: library not found for -llua

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip_build_root/aerospike/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-CQ0_XS-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip_build_root/aerospike
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 185, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
    text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: install lua with brew?

Comment: Did that, and I still get the same issue

Answer (score 5):

I faced similar problem, but providing the path to directory containing the library explicitly (via `LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable) worked for me.

First locate the directory which contains the file `liblua.a` (it was in `/usr/local/lib` directory on my machine, after I installed lua from source):

```
export LIBRARY_PATH='/usr/local/lib'  # or whichever directory contains liblua.a/liblua.dylib on your machine
sudo -E bash -c 'pip install aerospike'
```

Answer (score 1):

Aerospike is supported on OS X in a virtual machine managed by Vagrant.

After you have installed a Vagrant and a virtualization system, follow these steps:
-   create an Aerospike directory
-   Initialize the Aerospike Virtual Machine
-   Start Aerospike
-   Verify that Aerospike & the Aerospike Management console are running
-   Verify that the server was installed correctly
-   Pick a client and start developing.

Full instructions are available on Aerospike’s website here: 
http://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/install/vagrant/mac

Answer (score 1):

People, we're talking about the Aerospike client for Python on OS X. I can ensure you that it installs, as I develop on OS X mainly :)

The latest [release 1.0.48](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-python/releases/tag/1.0.48) has a Python wheel for OS X, meaning it contains a pre-built binary package. Check that your `pip` is up-to-date (>= 1.5) and has setuptools updated. Do a `pip install wheel` then `sudo pip install aerospike` once more.

Answer (score 0):

Hy,

Why don't you use the docker container from Aerospike web site ?

I'm not sure Aerospike will work directly on MacOs.

Emmanuel.

Comment: The server works on 64-bit Linux, the clients run on Linux and OS X.